# Cannot install Ecplise on Mac:A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm new to Java and found it's hard to install on my Mac. I read similar past questions and tried their solutions, but none works.

So far, I installed the latest version of jdk-14 and use eclipse-java-mars-2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar. Also, I tried add -vm to eclipse.ini. Now it's like:

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin"
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

But still got error message saying A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPOoY.png)

Yet without this line, the error is "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine".

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: What's the use of that `vm` option?

Comment: While, without it the error is "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine". I searched on line and a common suggestion is adding -vm PATH.

Comment: Check if the folder exists and if a `java` executable exist in the folder. Or just uninstall them all, then use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install, you'll need it sooner or later. Just paste the line in the webpage to Terminal to install brew, then `brew cask install eclipse-java`. Package managers like Homebrew will handle the rest for you.

Comment: No need for Homebrew, that is overkill. Delete all the JVMs currently found in `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. Then head to AdoptOpenJDK and download a Mac-specific installer. Easy-peasey. But use the long-term support LTS version of Java, Java 11. Wait on Java 14 until it has been proven to work well with Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't current run with Java 14. That is a very old version of Eclipse - use the current 2020-03

Comment: Note that if you insist on running Eclipse Mars (5 years and 10 releases old) then you must use Java 8, anything later will not work.